# How to select elements in a forEach loop? D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to modify an attribute in my links for a passed in Node object.

I am getting this error:

```
this.setAttribute is not a function
```

I am wondering what the restrictions are on the select operator. This is my current implementation:

```
function setChildrenLinkWidth(node) {
    node.links().forEach(function (i) {
        d3.select(i.source)
        .attr("stroke", "blue");
     });
 }
```

If anyone knows, I would appreciate it.

For reference, I have tried

```
d3.select("#" + i.source)
```

And I get the error:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#[object Object]' is not a valid selector.
```

Edit:

Here is some more code:

```
    // Creating nodes here
    let nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);
nodeEnter.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'node')

 // Functions

function setChildrenLinkWidth(node) {
node.links().forEach(function (i) {
    console.log(i.source);
    d3.select(i.source.id)
    attr("stroke", "blue");
 });
}

function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
    setChildrenLinkWidth(d);
}
```

Comment: what is `i.source`?

Comment: The source of the link.

Comment: Do you get an error when you use `d3.select("#" + i.source)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was mistaken. I need to edit my question. When I use your suggestion, I get the error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#[object Object]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: that is what I want to know `console.log(i.source);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because that `i.source` is the node that is the source and not simply the string you likely think you're getting based on the data... Therefore if you do `d3.select("#" + i.source.id);` it will select the element with that ID. Unless your `i.source` for each links is an object.

I can clarify more if you post your data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, using your suggestion got me the same error as I posted. d, in this case, must be an object.

Comment: Please post your data, or at least an example of its structure. I'm sure we can solve the problem then!

Comment: Ok, I added some more.

Comment: What is output of `console.log(i.source)`? If that is outputting [Object object] change it to `console.dir`, that should help discover what it actually is

Comment: Changing it gets me [vo] objects for each of the Links for the passed in Node.

Comment: So since you can see the structure of `i.source` from that, you should be able to modify the selection so that it selects the ID of the link appropriately

Comment: Still the same error as before. Not sure what the deal is.